# Using lstinputlisting with tex4ht hides all ASCII characters in the caption?

Tags: listings, tex4ht, utf8, vietnamese

I'm using tex4ht to build my LaTex source to EPUB. Currently I'm having problems with `lstinputlisting`, where the caption (in Vietnamese) isn't showing up correctly.

```
\lstinputlisting[float,language=C++,caption={Một chú thích viết bằng tiếng Việt.}]{data.cpp}
```

[image]

I examined the intermediate XHTML file generated from tex4ht, seems like every ASCII character in the caption is stripped, leaving only the Vietnamese character. The last visible, non-ASCII one is "dangled" to the next scope:

```html
... [redacted]
<body>
<!-- l. 8 --><p>Đạ ộúíếằế</p><pre class='lstinputlisting' id='listing-1'><span class='label'><a id='x1-4r1'></a><span class='ec-lmr-7'>ệ</span></span><span style='color:#000000'><span class='ec-lmtti-10x-x-90'>//</span></span><span style='color:#000000'> <span class='ec-lmtti-10x-x-90'>file.cpp</span> 
... [redacted]
```

... so that the entire caption "**Đ**o**ạ**n code 1: M**ộ**t ch**ú** th**í**ch vi**ế**t b**ằ**ng ti**ế**ng Vi**ệ**t." is stripped to "Đạ ộúíếằế" and "ệ" (dangling character).

To my surprise, if I use the `lstlisting` environment, tex4ht doesn't seem to have any problem with the Vietnamese caption. However, I can't use this as a workaround since my project will have a lot of standalone code files.
[image]

Any idea with regards to why is it happening? I've attached a [minimal reproducible example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gIIqolLsci020hf3tqiCB_tNm4fSL7Mt/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate my current project (build script is written in Batch script since I'm using a Windows machine).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I won't download and debug an example from an external source, such links will be dead at some time. Add a small but complete example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX4ht uses some special instructions to suppress unwanted characters in `\lstinputlisting`. Otherwise, some unwanted code would be inserted to the HTML output. Unfortunately, the caption is suppressed as well. We need to  turn off the character suppression here. It can be done using this version of `listings.4ht`:

```
% listings.4ht (2022-05-22-13:50), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2001-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-05-22-13:50}

\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{}{%
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
}
\def\lst@makecaption#1#2{\cptA: #1\if :#1:\else\cptB:\fi \cptC: #2\cptD:}

\newif\iflstnest
\append:defII\lst@EnterMode{%
  \ifx \lsthk:EveryLine\:UnDef
     \let\lsthk:EveryLine\lsthk@EveryLine
  \fi
  \ifx \lsthk:EveryLine\lsthk@EveryLine
      \pend:def\lsthk@EveryLine{\c:listings
             \def\dd:listings{\d:listings\let\dd:listings\empty}}%
  \fi
  \append:def\lsthk@EveryPar{\dd:listings}%
  \iflstnest\else
  \a:listings\fi\bgroup
  %\Configure{$}{}{}{}%
  \aftergroup\lst:EnterMode  }
\def\lst:EnterMode{\iflstnest\else\b:listings\fi\egroup}
\NewConfigure{listings}{4}
\let\dd:listings=\empty
\append:defI\lst@Init{\csname a:listings-init\endcsname\global\lstnesttrue}
\pend:def\lst@DeInit{\csname b:listings-init\endcsname\global\lstnestfalse}
\NewConfigure{listings-init}{2}
\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{%
   \Configure{listings}{}{}{}{}%
   \a:lstinline \bgroup \aftergroup\b:lstinline\aftergroup\egroup
  }
\NewConfigure{lstinline}{2}
\pend:defI\lst@MakeCaption{%
  \let\lst:addcontentsline\addcontentsline
  \def\addcontentsline{\gHAdvance\TitleCount by 1
                       \lst:addcontentsline}%
}
\append:defI\lst@MakeCaption{%
  \let\addcontentsline\lst:addcontentsline
}
\ConfigureToc{lol} {}{\empty}{}{\newline}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup%
    \ifdefined\chapter\chapter*{\lstlistlistingname}\else\section*{\lstlistlistingname}\fi%
    \TableOfContents[lol]%
  \egroup}
\def\:tempa{%
   \ifx\lst@OutputBox\@gobble\else \the\everypar \fi
   \global\advance\lst@newlines\m@ne
   \lst@newlinetrue
}%
\HLet\lst@NewLine\:tempa
\def\:tempa#1{
    \begingroup%
      \lsthk@PreSet\gdef\lst@intname{#1}%
      \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\lst@set}%
      \lsthk@DisplayStyle%
      \catcode\active=\active%
      \a:lstinputlisting
      \ht:special{t4ht@[}
      \pend:def\cptA:{\ht:special{t4ht@]}}
      \append:def\cptD:{\ht:special{t4ht@[}}
      \lst@Init\relax 
      \let\lst@gobble\z@%
      \lst@SkipToFirst%
      \lst@ifprint \def\lst@next{\input{#1}}%
             \else \let\lst@next\@empty \fi%
      \ht:special{t4ht@]}
      \lst@next\ht:special{t4ht@[}\lst@DeInit\ht:special{t4ht@]}%
      \b:lstinputlisting%
    \endgroup}

\HLet\lst@InputListing\:tempa
\NewConfigure{lstinputlisting}{2}
\def\:tempa#1{%
   \setbox\z@\hbox{{\lst@currstyle{\kern#1}}}%
   \global\advance\lst@currlwidth \wd\z@
   \tmp:dim=#1 \let\:tempc=\empty
   \loop \ifdim \tmp:dim>\a:lst@Kern
      \advance \tmp:dim by -\a:lst@Kern
      \advance \tmp:dim by -\b:lst@Kern
      \append:def\:tempc{\:nbsp}%
   \repeat
   \setbox\z@\hbox{{\lst@currstyle{\:tempc}}}%
   \lst@OutputBox\z@}
\HLet\lst@Kern\:tempa
\NewConfigure{lst@Kern}{2}
\Configure{lst@Kern}{0.499em}{0.1em}
\def\lst@outputspace{\HCode{ }}

\HLet\lst@frameInit=\empty
\HLet\lst@frameExit=\empty

\Hinput{listings}
\endinput
```

The important part is this code:

```
\def\:tempa#1{
    \begingroup%
      \lsthk@PreSet\gdef\lst@intname{#1}%
      \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\lst@set}%
      \lsthk@DisplayStyle%
      \catcode\active=\active%
      \a:lstinputlisting
      \ht:special{t4ht@[}
      \pend:def\cptA:{\ht:special{t4ht@]}}
      \append:def\cptD:{\ht:special{t4ht@[}}
      \lst@Init\relax 
      \let\lst@gobble\z@%
      \lst@SkipToFirst%
      \lst@ifprint \def\lst@next{\input{#1}}%
             \else \let\lst@next\@empty \fi%
      \ht:special{t4ht@]}
      \lst@next\ht:special{t4ht@[}\lst@DeInit\ht:special{t4ht@]}%
      \b:lstinputlisting%
    \endgroup}

\HLet\lst@InputListing\:tempa
```

This is the code for `\lstinputlisting`, we enable text in caption using these specials:

```
      \pend:def\cptA:{\ht:special{t4ht@]}}
      \append:def\cptD:{\ht:special{t4ht@[}}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

% \usepackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Đoạn code}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\lstdefinestyle{customstyle}
{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
  }
\lstset{language=C++, style=customstyle}

\begin{document}

%%%% NB: This doesn't show the caption correctly, ASCII characters are omitted
\lstinputlisting[float,language=C++,caption={Một chú thích viết bằng tiếng Việt.}]{data.cpp}

%%%% NB: This, surprisingly, show the caption correctly
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption={Một chú thích viết bằng tiếng Việt.}]
int main() { return 0; }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

It includes file `data.cpp`:

```c++
// file.cpp
int gInitialised = 1234;
float gUninitialised;
const bool gIsFinal = false;
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: That version of listings.4ht solves it, thank you very much @michal.h21